# Change the language for Google Pay Client API in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, google-pay

I have requirement to set local language to the Google Pay Client API. But i didn't find the way to change it.

Can you please help me in this. Thanks in advance

I have tried to set locale in payment request, but it is not working